# Google Chart with table giving "[object Object] does not fit the Control specification" Error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-api, google-visualization

i am trying to implement Google Dashboard with graph connected to dataTable,

This is my script

```
      <script type="text/javascript">

            function drawVisualization(dataArray) {
                //                function drawVisualization() {
                // Prepare the data
                var data = google.visualization.DataTable(dataArray);
                // Define a Pie chart
                var pie = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                    'chartType': 'PieChart',
                    'containerId': 'chart1',
                    'options': {
                        'width': 300,
                        'height': 300,
                        'legend': 'none',
                        'title': 'Donuts eaten per person',
                        'chartArea': {'left': 15, 'top': 15, 'right': 0, 'bottom': 0},
                        'pieSliceText': 'label'
                    },
                    // Instruct the piechart to use colums 0 (Name) and 3 (Donuts Eaten)
                    // from the 'data' DataTable.
                    'view': {'columns': [0, 5]}
                });

                // Define a table
                var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                    'chartType': 'Table',
                    'containerId': 'chart2',
                    'options': {
                        'width': '300px'
                    }
                });

                // Create a dashboard
                new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).
                    // Establish bindings, declaring the both the slider and the category
                // picker will drive both charts.
                bind([pie, table]).

                    // Draw the entire dashboard.
                draw(data);
            }

        </script>
 //My dataArray looks some thing like this [["039 - EXTRACRANIAL PROCEDURES W\/O CC\/MCC","AL","879","29855.3481218009","5857.17519906485","2"],["039 - EXTRACRANIAL PROCEDURES W\/O CC\/MCC","AZ","606","33581.3151824257","7034.48184806271","4"],["039 - EXTRACRANIAL PROCEDURES W\/O CC\/MCC","CO","255","33554.1607857647","6911.51372542745","6"],["039 - EXTRACRANIAL PROCEDURES W\/O CC\/MCC","DC","47","44919.3829785106","9241.59574459574","8"],....
```

I dont know why i am getting this error.

Comment: Can you see the error in Console of Your browser (F12/Console) ? If yes click on the error and post here the line code. And where your datable comes from ?

Comment: Nope no error in the console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
bind([pie, table]).
```

The Dashboard.bind method expects two arguments: an array of controls and an array of charts.  The first array is for the controls, and the API is throwing an error because it is finding charts where it expects controls.  The Dashboards do not support using charts without controls.  If you want to draw your charts, you need to specify the `dataTable` parameter of each chart and call the wrappers' draw methods individually:

```
var pie = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'PieChart',
    'containerId': 'chart1',
    dataTable: data,
    'options': {
        'width': 300,
        'height': 300,
        'legend': 'none',
        'title': 'Donuts eaten per person',
        'chartArea': {'left': 15, 'top': 15, 'right': 0, 'bottom': 0},
        'pieSliceText': 'label'
    },
    // Instruct the piechart to use colums 0 (Name) and 3 (Donuts Eaten)
    // from the 'data' DataTable.
    'view': {'columns': [0, 5]}
});
pie.draw();

// Define a table
var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'Table',
    'containerId': 'chart2',
    dataTable: data,
    'options': {
        'width': '300px'
    }
});
table.draw();
```

Also, your DataTable construction is incorrect.  Since you are passing an array of data, you need to use the `arrayToDataTable` method:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);
```

The data in your array is missing a column header row (which should be the first row) - you either need to add that row, or pass `true` as a second parameter to the `arrayToDataTable` method.  Also, the numbers in your data are wrapped as strings, which will cause problems with your PieChart.  Remove the quotes around the numbers to fix.

Comment: arrayToDataTable throws me this error, "Error: Not an array" so that was is the reason i switched to dataTable

Comment: , I got the point where you referred about bind function of dashboard , but the problem is if i replace datatable to arrayToDataTable i get error

Comment: Is your array actually an array, or is it a string?  If it's a string, you can convert it to an array via `JSON.parse`.  If you would rather use the standard DataTable constructor, then there are a bunch of other changes you will have to make.

Comment: I have array of strings

Comment: If it is an actual array, you would not get the error message "Error: Not an array".  Insert the line `console.log(dataArray, typeof(dataArray));` before the `var data = ` line, open the page in Chrome, and view the developer's console (you can open from the chrome menu or hit ctrl+shift+j).  What is output in the console?

Comment: yes its an array of strings, so the Integer Control which was bar, was thorwing this error i removed that control and not its working great.